# no output in custom created views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i created a controller article and added the following code

```
def chid
  @message='hello world'
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    end

end
```

I then created

```
chid.html.erb
```

file in

```
app/views/articles/
```

and wrote the following code

```
Hello world
```

When i gave the following url

```
../articles/chid
```

i dunnot get any output.. am i missing something?

My log portion

```
Processing ArticlesController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-12 21:51:01)
 [GET] Session ID: BAh7BzoMY3NyZl9pZCIlMTA0ZWY2ZTUzYjQxZGJkZmFlMTQwNWRjYjczNTRm%0AODAiCmZsYXNoSUM6J0FjdGlvbkNvbnRyb2xsZXI6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhh%0Ac2h7AAY6CkB1c2VkewA%3D--de7737601817f52c1b72daca6061c5126f3a5022
 Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"chid", "controller"=>"articles"}
 Rendering template within layouts/articles 
Rendering articles/show Completed in 0.01000 (100 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00600 (60%) | DB: 0.00000 (0%) | 200 OK [localhost/articles/chid/]
```

my router.rb file is as follows

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :articles
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
   map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
   map.match ':controller/:action/' => 'Article#chid'
 end
```

Comment: @Matheus: No. wat should i do in there? sorry am jus learning ROR

Comment: @Matheus: The page is being correctly rendered.. But there s no output

Comment: @jdl. is this what u asked?                        Processing ArticlesController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-12 21:51:01) [GET]
  Session ID: BAh7BzoMY3NyZl9pZCIlMTA0ZWY2ZTUzYjQxZGJkZmFlMTQwNWRjYjczNTRm%0AODAiCmZsYXNoSUM6J0FjdGlvbkNvbnRyb2xsZXI6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhh%0Ac2h7AAY6CkB1c2VkewA%3D--de7737601817f52c1b72daca6061c5126f3a5022
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"chid", "controller"=>"articles"}
Rendering template within layouts/articles
Rendering articles/show
Completed in 0.01000 (100 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00600 (60%) | DB: 0.00000 (0%) | 200 OK [http://localhost/articles/chid/]

Comment: The server process it as though , the show action was invoked with id chid.. it doesnot call the action chid.. this s what i understood from logs. @jdl

Comment: You need to add a special case to your routes to match the `chid` action since it is not a CRUD operation. In this case, it is interpreting `chid` as the `id` of the article and attempting to `show` on it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Probably better to edit that into your question than paste it into a comment, but it shows that it's clearly a routing problem. Looks like Matheus is pointing you in the right direction below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `config` directory there is a file named `routes.rb`. This file tells Rails how to respond to certain URLs by mapping them a controller's action.

Consider the example:

```
match '/articles/chid' => 'Articles#chid'
```

This will route `#{your_site_url}/articles/chid` to `ArticlesController`'s `chid` action, which in turn would render the `chid.html.erb` view located in `views/articles`.

We can also tell Rails what to route `/` to as well:

```
root :to => 'Articles#chid'
```

And, finally, we could also route any controller to any action using what's called Bound Parameters:

```
match ':controller/:action'
```

As a last note, definitely check out the [Rails Guides on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html).

**Update**:

Try using the following `routes.rb`:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect ':controller/:action'
end
```

**Edit**

Based on the routes.rb file you just posted, this line is the culprit. Delete it.

`map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'`

Note that the routes match in order from the top of the file to the bottom and once it finds a match, it's done. It won't look at the rest of your routes.

Comment: @Matheus. I addedd the follwing line in routes.rb                map.match ':controller/articles/chid' => 'Articles#chid'. Still it shows record not found with id=chid.

Comment: If i dunnot specify the controller, its giving me an error. i am using rails 2.0.2

Comment: Do you have `map.resources :articles` anywhere in your `routes.rb`? If so, try adding `map.match '/articles/chid' => 'Articles#chid'` before that, or just removing it altogheter. (By the way, the instructions I gave were for Rails 3... but they should work with minor modifications, I think)

Comment: ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

      map.resources :articles

    map.resources :articles                                     
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

  map.match 'articles/chid' => 'Articles#chid'                    
This is the content of my router file. Still i get the same error :( 
My model name is Article.

Comment: Unless you've got more actions on your `ArticlesController`, you only need to match the `chid` action, so `ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map| map.match '/articles/chid' => 'Articles#chid' end` should do it. Replace the entire content with that. If you have more actions, try replacing `'/articles/chid'` with `':controller/:action'`.

Comment: thank you very much Matheus. I have more than one action in `ArticlesController`, and i added the line `map.match ':controller/:action/' => 'Article#chid'`. Still it fetches the show action with `id=chid`.

Comment: @CHID I suspect that everyone is very close here. Please post your routes file (edited into the original question not as a comment).  The entire file, not just the line you're trying to fix.

Comment: You shouldn't specify the controller and action when using bound parameters, `:controller/:action` will match `Article#chid`, `Article#new`, `Comment#create` and all other possible combinations. Try commenting out every other line in your `routes.rb` and adding `map.match ':controller/:action'` as the _only_ line.

Comment: @jdl, i have added my router.rb file

Comment: @matheus. I commented out all the lines in my file. These were the only lines present. `ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|            map.resources :articles        map.match ':controller/:action/' => 'Article#chid'     end`. Still i am getting the same error :(

Comment: @matheus. the updated answer worked :) thank you very much. But pls can u explain wat it changed?

Comment: @Matheus I edited in a note about the offending line and a brief explanation of why that was causing problems. Hopefully I did screw up your answer, but I didn't think that my note warranted a separate answer.

Comment: That's great! jdl updated my answer with an explanation on why the lines before that one were getting in the way.

Comment: @CHID You're welcome! @jdl Don't worry about it. There was a right answer in the end, that's what matters!